# regex extract word group before the end of line

Tags: regex

I have following samples of strings

```
commit: February 2021 Master DS Commit c285fcbf59b698ec5695d35989a420da7659
commit: March market Sales Volume PFJan2021
commit: August market Input PFJan2021
commit: February 2021 Master DS Commit c5695d359820da7659
```

I want to extract words which are in between `commit:` and `Commit c285cb...` or the end of line. The result is as follows:

```
February 2021 Master DS
March market Sales Volume PFJan2021
August market Input PFJan2021
February 2021 Master DS
```

I understand that using following regex, I can extract words after `commit:`

`.*commit: (.*)`

I have tried another regex: `.*commit: (.*)Commit.*` but it returns blank where `Commit` word doesn't exist (I believe that's the expected behaviour).

Is there a way to use some style of `or` condition which checks if `Commit` word exists return words before it and after `commit:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
commit:\s*(.*?)(?:\s*Commit\b|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ykQ7FM/1).

*Details*:

- `commit:` - a literal string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:\s*Commit\b|$)` - either zero or more whitespaces and `Commit` as a whole word or end of string.